# Error in query (1241): Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Tags: sql, mariadb

How to fix this error?

This query return a error: Error in query (1241): Operand should contain 1 column(s)

```
SELECT uti_id, uti_nome FROM utilizador WHERE uti_escola=1 AND uti_id IN 
(SELECT DISTINCT ens_utiid_escola, SQRT(POW(69.1 * (uti_latitude - ?), 2) + POW(69.1 * (? - uti_longitude) * COS(uti_latitude / 57.3), 2)) * 1.609344 AS distance
FROM utilizador LEFT OUTER JOIN ensino ON uti_id=ens_utiid WHERE uti_estado=1
AND uti_tipo=1 HAVING distance < ?) ORDER BY uti_nome
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is coming from this part of the query:

```
uti_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT ens_utiid_escola, SQRT(POW(69.1 * (uti_latitude - ?), 2) + POW(69.1 * (? - uti_longitude) * COS(uti_latitude / 57.3), 2)) * 1.609344 AS distance
```

First, you don't need `select distinct` in an `in` subquery.  Second, the error is because you have two rows.  So if you want to use this logic:

```
uti_id IN (SELECT ens_utiid_escola
           FROM . . .
          )
```

Then you need to repeat the expression for `distance` where you us it.